# Ionic 4 Native Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) not working at all

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic4, ionic-native

I cannot get a project with the [latest Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started) (4) working with [Ionic Native BLE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble) on either Android or iOS. When adding this plugin, the app starts but goes completely blank after the splash screen. When inspecting the DOM, app-root is empty.

What I did:

- New Ionic project with `ionic start ble-test tabs`
- Install BLE with `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central` and
  `npm install @ionic-native/ble`
- Add the plugin to app.module.ts:

```js
    import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble';
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [...],
      providers: [
        ...,
        BLE
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I noticed the point of failure is when BLE is added to the list of providers. Without that, the app starts up just fine. With BLE added to the list, the white screen comes and the app does not start fully.

As this issue is recreatable with very minimal code, I believe something is fundamentally wrong with the BLE plugin. I hope to be proven wrong, but after hours of searching I cannot get to the bottom of this.

Full disclosure: I have also tried [Ionic Native BluetoothLE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/bluetoothle/), which has the same issue (which makes me believe even more that something is fundamentally wrong). [BluetoothSerial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial) does not crash the app, but it does not offer the kind of functionality I am looking for.

Comment: import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';

Comment: When I use this, I get "cannot find module '@ionic-native/ble/ngx'."

Comment: this is the case of conflict between the capacitor and Cordova

Comment: ionic start myApp tabs --cordova

Comment: bcoz you are using BLE Cordova plugin

Comment: ionic start --type=ionic-angular   this for ionic 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I was using a cached version of an older BLE version.

---

Thanks to for Aashay karekar noticing that my include path was off. However, when I used the correct path, Ionic could not find the specified (but correct) path. This made me look into versioning and I deleted the BLE from my package.json manually and removed the node_modules folder. When I then installed BLE again, everything worked fine.